# Как установить пакет Rmpfr в R на Fedora 24

Tags: r

Помогите установить пакет Rmpfr в R.
При установке выдаёт ошибку

```
configure: error: GNU MP not found, or not 4.1.4 or up, see http://gmplib.org
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘gmp’
* removing ‘/home/dmitryi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/gmp’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘gmp’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘gmp’ is not available for package ‘Rmpfr’
* removing ‘/home/dmitryi/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/Rmpfr’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘Rmpfr’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/tmp/RtmppouTT8/downloaded_packages’
```

Это проблема именно на Fedora24. На Ubuntu 16.04 установилось без проблем.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ.

```
sudo yum install gmp gmp-devel mpfr mpfr-devel libmpc libmpc-devel
```